# Get numbers between quotes and backslash with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Following is my string:

```
"\"26201\",7\0\"
```

Quotes are part of the string. I want to get the number **26201** out of it using regular expressions.

Similarly, I want to extract number **123** out of `"\"123\",7111\0000\"`.

This is actually where I am stuck:

```cs
string input = "\"\\\"123\\\",7\\0\\0\"";
System.Console.WriteLine($"input is {input}");
string firstPattern = @"[0-9]{0,10}\\""";
Regex extractRelevantRgx = new Regex(firstPattern);
MatchCollection matches = extractRelevantRgx.Matches(input);
            
//here i get 2 match 1st is \" and second is 26201\"
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    //now trying to get only numbers from the second match
    Regex numberPatternRgx = new Regex(@"[0-9]{0,10}"); //to now seprate numbers
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        string substring = match.Value;
        MatchCollection results = numberPatternRgx.Matches(substring);
        // I should be getting only 1 match that also only for second match, instead I get 3 matches in first iteration alone
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            string resultfinal = results[0].Value;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"final result {resultfinal}");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with the code where I am stuck.

Comment: So, your literal text input is in fact `\"26201\",7\0\0`, right? It is not actually between quotes, it is between two ``\"``.

Comment: I believe all you need is https://ideone.com/IB1gvS, does it work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you needed to match a digit sequence between two double quotes, you could use `var resultfinal = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<="")[0-9]+(?="")")?.Value;`. However, your original string contains escaped quotation marks, so you need to extract a digit sequence in between two `\"` substrings.

You can use

```cs
var input = "\\\"26201\\\",7\\0\\0";
var firstPattern = @"(?<=\\"")[0-9]+(?=\\"")";
var resultfinal = Regex.Match(input, firstPattern)?.Value;
Console.WriteLine($"final result: '{resultfinal}'");
// => final result: '26201'
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/IB1gvS). The pattern is `(?<=\\")[0-9]+(?=\\")`, see [its online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5C%22%29%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5C%5C%22%29&i=%5C%2226201%5C%22%2C7%5C0%5C0). *Details*:

- `(?<=\\")` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `\"` substring to occur immediately to the left of the current location
- `[0-9]+` - one or more ASCII digits (note `\d+` matches any one or more Unicode digits including Hindi, Persian etc. digits unless the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option is used)
- `(?=\\")` -  a positive lookahead that requires a `\"` substring to occur immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression like `^"(?<someGroupName>\d+)"`. You'll have to escape the quotes to get it into a C# string.

This matches the start of the string with `^` followed by a literal " character followed by one or more digits followed by another literal " character. The digits are captured in a group called `someGroupName`, which you would want to change to be something more meaningful.

Here is a link to this regular expression running on regex101.com. They have a searchable quick reference section and also give awesome live updating explanations of what your regex is doing.

https://regex101.com/r/TovYcQ/1

Here is a link to a dotnetfiddle where you can see this running in the context of a C# test bed:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pb09Vm

Answer (score 0):

Did you try trim(""").split(""")[0]?

Comment: although the above did not work, it took me towards one possible solution:
string numberResult = input.Trim('"').Split('"')[1].Split('\\')[0];